# I can operate any stick shift without the owner's manual; can I operate any front derailleur with no manual?

Tags: shifting, derailleur-front

### Car stick shifts vs. bike front-derailleur operation

We thankfully have a standard for driving automobiles. We can operate a new or a rental car without reading its owner's manual. Reading the manual is useful for many basic details, but the steering wheel, braking, and, especially, shifting are universal.

When bikes do come with an "owner's manual", the manual is written by lawyers ("do not operate without a helmet") and addresses neither basic maintenance nor even operation. It's necessary to search for the actual documents online. The details of operating front derailleurs in conjunction with rear derailleurs have subtleties that make riding a new bike inherently iterative to avoid all chain-cage rubbing.

### 2x Front derailleurs and the mysterious third middle position

Many **2x** (road bike) front-shifter-and-front-derailleur sets have **three** settings.

The derailleur-cage-at-its-leftmost setting is used for, vaguely, the 50% of larger-cogs **rear**-derailleur settings. Those are positions I and III in the illustration (although the large-chainring-largest-cog is unlikely to be usable; the chain will most likely rub on the front derailleur cage).

The derailleur-cage-at-its-rightmost setting is likewise used, again roughly, for the 50% of smaller-cogs **rear**-derailleur settings. Those are illustrated in II and IV in the figure (the smaller-smallest chainring-to-cog is likewise generally unusable).

### Illustration

[image: front derailleur shifting]

### Question

Is there a standard for knowing whether the middle of the **front**-derailleur shifter is to be used for II only, for III only, or for both II and III?

In other words, when you start riding an unfamiliar bike, do you have to search for its Operator Manual (online, probably) to learn how to shift properly?

#### Indexed Shifting

Indexed shifting (which is now so widespread it may have completely pushed friction shifting out of the new-bike market for years) greatly helps with the leftmost and rightmost cage positions. The shifting interface consists of a clean click. Each click lands on a precise setting.

If we access the middle position from the large-chainring, we cleanly drop to an indexed position, but I haven't been able to determine whether accessing the middle position from the small-chainring (pulling the cable more taut and lifting the derailleur cage halfway) will always pull the cage also to an indexed position. Does it?

Comment: Isn't the standard whether or not the front derailleur is rubbing on the chain? You talk about three settings - based on the context of the question you are talking about a friction shifter. It does not have three settings, it is analog.

Comment: @DavidD most modern (SRAM and Shimano) derailleurs have a middle "trim" position.

Comment: @PaulH Aren't most SRAM and Shimano derailleurs indexed? He addresses indexed shifting later in the section titled "Index Shifting". Even so, isn't the standard whether or not the front derailleur is rubbing?

Comment: @DavidD To be honest, I'm having trouble parsing the question at all. My point is that modern indexed derailleurs for double chainrings have 3 positions.

Comment: @DavidD He's talking about 3 discrete positions, therefore he must be talking about indexed shifting.  A friction shifter doesn't have any set positions, you just put it where it needs to go.

Comment: @PaulH at least three positions!

Comment: @Swifty more than three would be news to me. Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: I'm still not clear what the question is.  Are you asking if the trim position accessed by shifting to the large chainring and then trimming, the same physical position of the derailleur as the trim position accessed by shifting to the small chainring and then trimming?

Comment: @PaulH see the diagram above numbered one through four

Comment: @DavidW I think the question is how do you know in advance, how to access each position, without looking it up in a manual for each model.

Comment: @Swifty that diagram shows 4 positions of the rear derailleur. I'm talking about the *front* derailleur. The answer to that question determined by whether or not the chain is rubbing

Comment: @PaulH https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/84915/38558

Comment: @Swifty, sure, but that's not what Diagram IV is showing at all

Comment: @PaulH ok, page 19 https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-RAFD001-02-ENG.pdf see v w x and y. four positions

Comment: @Swifty thanks -- that's fundamentally different that the OP's diagram

Comment: Maybe this is why 1x is so popular.  FD's confuse everyone :P

Comment: @AndyP fair comment

Comment: Note that the extremely wide inter-compatibility of bicycle parts means that a operating manual is not always very helpful. People tend to keep their cars in the factory configuration, so it works well there.

Comment: @AndyP not everyone, but those who can operate one aren't telling about it everywhere

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many left road shifters, including almost all recent higher end ones, have four positions, i.e. there's a trim stop for both the small and large ring.

There is not, nor in practical terms could there be, a standard for what gear combination requires the use of which shifter stop, because the angle of the chain coming off the chainring is meaningfully dependent on chainstay length.

Bikes with long chainstays (say 440mm or more) allow some greater laziness with the trim stops, and bikes with very short chainstays, particularly less than the common 405mm minimum recommended for road groups, can require one to fidget with the trim stops often. (Many TT/tri bikes break the 405mm rule).

Frame alignment is a factor as well. The industry standard (for better or for worse) is that misalignment up to 3mm in either direction is normal, as measured with a tool like the Park Frame Alignment Gauge. That means a possible variance of 3mm (1.5mm possible in each direction), which is a good chunk of the cog pitch of modern cassettes. So even on two of the same model bike, frame alignment could require a different trim stop used on the same gear combination.